# Toggle part of a ViewFlipper view in android

Tags: android, viewflipper

I am using a ViewFlipper to toggle between views. I would like to get the same effect as Facebook's or Youtube's settings views, which is to keep a bit of the last view showing to the right. See image below. How can I do this?

[image]

Comment: Are you using a ViewFlipper or a ViewPager? I know there are ways to do that kind of thing in the ViewPager, but a ViewFlipper just stacks views on top of each other.

Comment: I am actually using both. A ViewFlipper to divide larger areas of the application, and a ViewPager for a smaller part of it. I guess I could redo it and only use the ViewPager if that would help me!

Comment: yeah. i would suggest using a viewpager if you want to page left and right and a viewflipper if you just want to have content change on its own.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I wish there was a way to accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using a ViewFlipper, try a ViewPager. The ViewPager is best, I think, if you want to have different pages and let the user control which one they see. It uses the paging animation by default, and you can specify page width so the user can see parts of the page next to it.